# Open query - Oracle with clause

Tags: sql-server, oracle, openquery

It is possible to use SQL Server's Open Query, with Oracle With AS clause, in query?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(OMSP, 
'
WITH OrderReserve AS
 (SELECT cvwarehouseid,
 lproductid,
 SUM(lqty) lqty
 FROM iOrdPrdQtyDate
 GROUP BY cvwarehouseid,
 lproductid) 

SELECT CGPCPRD.DWPRDOID, V_LPRODUCTID_DWBOBJECTOID.DWBOBJECTOID
FROM xxx.CGPCPRD CGPCPRD
...
LEFT JOIN OrderReserve ON (
        OrderReserve.cvWarehouseId = CGCCWAREHOUSEPARTY.CVWAREHOUSEID 
        AND OrderReserve.lProductId = V_LPRODUCTID_DWBOBJECTOID.LPRODUCTID
        ) 
')
```

Without this (and join which use this With AS) query works. I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OMSP" returned
>   message "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". Msg 7321, Level 16,
>   State 2, Line 1 An error occurred while preparing the query " WITH
>   OrderReserve AS  (SELECT cvwarehouseid,  lproductid,  SUM(lqty) lqty 
>   FROM iOrdPrdQtyDate  GROUP BY cvwarehouseid,  lproductid)  ...

This passed query works in Oracle.